# SAS - How to run a array over multiple files

Tags: arrays, macros, sas

I have multiple files with the same naming conventions and same data format: Dsn1 to Dsn7.

At the moment I am running the following

```
data temp (drop=i); set Dsn1;
array S_(12) S_AUD--S_USD;
do i=1 to 12;
S_[i] = log(S_{i}); 
end;
```

I have not been able to figure out how to do this for all files?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. You could create a macro and run it for each file. Or you can run it for all files at once and create a 'big' file.

```
data temp (drop=i); 
     set Dsn1 - dsn7;
     array S_(12) S_AUD--S_USD;
     do i=1 to 12;
           S_[i] = log(S_{i}); 
     end;
run;
```

Macro approach:

```
%macro loop (num_datasets=);
  %do i=1 %to &num_datasets;

 data temp&i. (drop=i); 
 set Dsn&i;
 array S_(12) S_AUD--S_USD;
 do i=1 to 12;
       S_[i] = log(S_{i}); 
 end;
 run;

%end;

 %mend;

%loop(num_datasets=5);
```

The macro appendix in the documentation has several examples of how this can work:

https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/SAS-9-4-Macro-Language-Reference-Has-a-New-Appendix/ta-p/291716

Comment: thank you for your help. I need to run it for each file (they need to be kept seperate)